A possible property about diffeomorphism

There are good counterexamples for $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n\ge 1$ in the answers. I also want to know under what condition can I say $U\backslash U_0$ has Lebesgue measure $0$?

Let $U,V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be two open sets, $U$ is connected, and
$$
H : \ \ U \longrightarrow V 
$$
is a smooth surjective. Assume that $H|_{U_0} : U_0 \rightarrow V_0$ is a diffeomorphism, where $U_0 \subset U$. Also, we assume $V\backslash V_0$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.
The question: $U\backslash U_0$ has Lebesgue measure $0$? You can also give counterexample (in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n\ge 2$ is better, counterexample in $\mathbb{R}$ is also welcome)
I think Morse-Sard-Federer theorem may help.  But I don't know how to apply this theorem.

Here is a counter-example in the case $n=2$. Think of $\mathbb R^2$ as the complex plane $\mathbb C$. Take $U=V=\mathbb C$, $U_0=\{z: Im(z)>0\}$ and $H(z)=z^2$. Then $H: U_0\to V_0$ is a diffeomorphism, where $V_0$ is the complement to $C=\{z: z\in \mathbb R, z\ge 0\}$. However, clearly, $U\setminus U_0$ has infinite measure while $C$ has zero measure. Extending this example to $\mathbb R^n=\mathbb R^2\times \mathbb R^{n-1}$ by
$$
F(x_1, x_2, x_3....,x_n)= (H(x_1,x_2), x_3,...,x_n)
$$
you get higher-dimensional counter-examples.

The other answer had shown that the statement is false when $n\ge 2$. We show here that the statement is also not true when $n=1$:
Let $U= \mathbb R$, and let $f :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be an non-deceasing function on on $U$ such that $f$ is constant on $[0,1]$, but is strictly increasing otherwise.
Then $V = f(\mathbb R)$ is open, and $ f|_{U_0} : U_0 \to V\setminus \{f(0)\}$ is a diffeomorphism, where $U _0 = \mathbb R\setminus [0,1]$.
